# moving subdirectories with the mv command

Tags: filenames, mv, working-directory

In the following structure, with a parent directory `K` and three subdirectories, `D`, `H`, and `B`, respectively, directly under it, my current directory is D. From there I need to move `H` as a subdirectory under `B`. Can this be done with the `mv` command without my first cd-ing into the parent directory `K`, which is not allowed (this is for an introductory course in Python 3) ? I've tried the following :

```
mv K/H K/B/
```

but get an error message, perhaps because superfluous directories are not permitted. I've also tried

```
mv /H /B/
```

but with the same lack of success....

Update : For some reason I'm unable to add a comment to this thread, which I myself, started, so I chose to comment in this way. steeldriver's comment gave me the inspiration needed to successfully complete the task before me. The commands I used were of type

```
mv ../H ../B/
```

rather than of type

```
mv ../K/H ../K/B/
```

Henri

Comment: Your first example looks fine, what error do you get?

Comment: *"my current directory is D"* so to get to `K` you need to go up: `mv ../H ../B/`

Comment: How moving files in *nix is connected with course in Python 3? Anyway, @steeldriver solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If a path begins with `/`, it starts from the root (i.e. the directory that doesn't have a parent¹). If a path doesn't begin with `/`, it starts from the current directory.

There are two special directory names: `.` always refers to the current directory, and `..` always refers to the parent of the current directory. So if you're in `D` which is a subdirectory of `K`, then you can refer to `K` as `..`. If you're in `D` then a plain `K` means the subdirectory of `D` called `K`, which is not what you want.

Thus the command you're looking for is

```
mv ../K/H ../K/B/
```

You could also use absolute paths, but you'd have to provide the whole path from the root. E.g. if `K` is actually `/home/henri/exercises/1/K` then you could write

```
mv /home/henri/exercises/1/K/H /home/henri/exercises/1/K/B/
```

¹  <sub>Technically, the root directory is actually its own parent.</sub>